# Ada : check if a result of division haven't decimal numbers

Tags: ada

I write my first ada program which include a condition that check if a value divide by a specific number haven't a decimal part :

EXEMPLE :

```
10 / 3 = 3.3333334 >> Wrong
12 / 2 = 6         >> Okay
45 / 5 = 9         >> Okay
...
```

But I can't find any function to do it...
this is my code :

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO ;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO ;

procedure main is
   ...
   testing : Natural := 0 ;
   ...

begin
   ...
         if testing/i = ??? then -- if testing/i haven't decimal part --
         ...
         end if ;
...
end main ;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? what is you strategy to achieve such a goal ? Is this just homework ?

Answer (score 2):

This could work:

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO; 

procedure Main is

   procedure Test_Remainder (X, Y : Integer) is
      use Ada.Text_IO;
   begin

      --  Optional: add some test for Y being non-zero here...

      Put (X'Image & " / " & Y'Image & "  ==>  ");       

      if (X rem Y = 0) then
         Put_Line ("Okay");
      else
         Put_Line ("Wrong");
      end if;

   end Test_Remainder;

begin   
   Test_Remainder (10, 3);
   Test_Remainder (12, 2);
   Test_Remainder (45, 5);
end Main;
```

**output**

```
 10 /  3  ==>  Wrong
 12 /  2  ==>  Okay
 45 /  5  ==>  Okay
```

*Note: For difference between `mod` and `rem` see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#In_programming_languages).*

Comment: is procedure inside procedure equivalent to definitions ?

Comment: You can always define a procedure (subprogram) in the declarative part (i.e. between `is` and `begin`) of another procedure. These are called nested subprograms. Their visibility is scoped to the subprogram in which they are defined (in this case, the visibility of `Test_Remainder` is scoped to `Main`). See also "Nested subprograms" on  [learn.adacore.com](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/subprograms.html#nested-subprograms).

Comment: You haven't explained your solution. How it find fraction part?

Comment: @Vovanium: Well, I don't compute the fractional part. I just test whether the (integer) division yields a remainder (using the `rem` operator). If it does, then the result of the floating-point division will not be an integer number and will have a fractional part. In your example: 10 / 3 = 3 (quotient) _with remainder 1_,
12 / 2 = 6 _with remainder 0_, 45 / 5 = 9 _with remainder 0_.